# GWT project doesn't compile, cannot resolve classes in same package

Tags: java, git, gwt

we're trying to run a little web application and just cannot get rid of these two errors:

```
Finding entry point classes
      Tracing compile failure path for type 'com.test4.project.client.Test4'
         [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/C:/Users/arik/OneDrive/workspaceHP/Test4/src/com/test4/project/client/Test4.java'
            [ERROR] com.test4.project.server.ImportHandler cannot be resolved to a type
         [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/C:/Users/arik/OneDrive/workspaceHP/Test4/src/com/test4/project/server/ImportHandler.java'
            [ERROR] Line 44: No source code is available for type java.text.SimpleDateFormat; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[WARN] Server class 'com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JDBCUnloader' could not be found in the web app, but was found on the system classpath
   [WARN] Adding classpath entry 'file:/C:/Users/arik/.p2/pool/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle_2.7.0/gwt-2.7.0/gwt-dev.jar' to the web app classpath for this session
   For additional info see: file:/C:/Users/arik/.p2/pool/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle_2.7.0/gwt-2.7.0/doc/helpInfo/webAppClassPath.html
```

Here is the link to our git repo: https://github.com/braunwiediefarbe/Test4/tree/new_Importer

The new Importer branch is the one we're working on, the other one just runs so we had something to show...

I'm using JDK 1.8 and SDK 2.7. I literally have no idea what it could be, we've tried everything we could find on google.

Thanks for the help!
Arik

Answer (score 1):

GWT compiles client-side code to javascript, this means that you cannot just run any java code on the client side if it does not have a Javascript "implementation".

SimpleDateFormat cannot be used in client-side code as it does not have any way of being compiled to Javascript, You can use [DateTimeFormat](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/DateTimeFormat.html) for client-side date formatting.